# Office 365 login with cloud credential in federated domain

Tags: office365, adfs, federation

I have got a little strange requirement. Requirement story is big so I will not spend your time on that. What I have to do is as follows;

1. I have a domain in office 365 (ex. contoso.com). The domain is using normal office 365 cloud authentication (i.e. its NOT YET federated)
2. It has ALREADY got few users (for example  nitin@contoso.com / asha@contoso.com and their password is for example P@ssw0rd)
3. I then went ahead and federated that domain with our ADFS.
4. Now, whenever I type in my username, it takes me to my ADFS login page.
5. there if I try to login with nitin@contoso.com, obviously it will not accept P@ssw0rd as a password since ADFS is NOT aware of cloud password.
6. What I want is, ONLY one time I need to login with cloud password on my ADFS page. I have a way to inject code on login page which can go and check cloud username / password. Just for testing, I have tried CSOM from console application but that too is NOT working because the domain is NOW federated.

Is there any other way I can still login with CLOUD credentials though the domain is federated?

As I said, if I am able to login ONLY 1 time, we are good.

Answer (score 0):

I think we will not be able to achieve this. If a domain is federated, it will go to ADFS which in turn goes to AD for Authentication. However, I can give you a pointer to this - The only way out there if we need to login One time would be to check if there is an option to achieve that in ADFS sign in page customization:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn636121(v=ws.11).aspx